# Strings of numbers to int

Tags: sql, converters

I have tables 'specifics', 'data' and 'categories'. In table 'specifics' I have dataID and categoryID. I have a query that selects all data and groups them by categoryID. I need to display them like:

```
1
1,2
3,4
5,6
10
11
```

but insted i get

```
1
1,2
10
11
3,4
5,6
```

they are not order by int because I have convertet as varchar:

```
select 
CONVERT(nvarchar(50), SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + convert(varchar(10), [data])
        FROM specifics WHERE categoryID = MIN(k.ID) and dataID= $id
            ), 2, 50)) DATAS
        from 
            specifics ts join category k on k.ID = ts.categoryID
        where
            ts.dataID= $id 
            group by k.ID order by DATAS
```

So my question is: how to convert or cast string of numbers to int and order by those int values?

Comment: If still relevant: Which database version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a portion of your nvarchar column back to an int type and use that in your ORDER BY clause. Perhaps something like this:

```
    ORDER BY CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(1,1, SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + convert(varchar(10), [data])))
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.